# How to Insert Method Inside MasterDetailPage XamarinForms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have masterdetailpage that have Logout function inside that (so instead navigating to other page it will shows display alert), but i dont know how to insert the logout method inside the masterdetailpage, i already tried using ICommand but  seem it didnt works and make my application force close . 
Here is my MasterPageItem Model

```
 public class MasterPageItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public Type TargetType { get; set; }
        public ICommand Commando { get; set; }



    }
```

here is the listview for MasterDetailPage

```
 <ListView x:Name="navigationDrawerList"
                  RowHeight="45"
                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                  BackgroundColor="#000000"
                  ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>

                                <!-- Main design for our menu items -->
                                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#000000" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Padding="20,10,0,10"
                             Spacing="20">

                                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                         WidthRequest="60"
                         HeightRequest="60"
                         VerticalOptions="Center" />

                                    <Label FontFamily="Panton-LightCaps.otf#Panton-LightCaps" Text="{Binding Title}"
                         FontSize="Medium"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         TextColor="White"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

and i tried to insert the method like this

```
 public ICommand GetOff { get; private set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
      GetOff = new Command(LogoutCommand) 
        var page9 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "LOGOUT",  Commando = GetOff  };


}


  public async void LogoutCommand ()
        {
            var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Do you really want to exit?", "Yes", "No");
            if (result == true)
            {
                App.AuthenticationClient.UserTokenCache.Clear(Constants.ApplicationID);
                Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new NewPageLogin());


            }
        }
```

Is there another way to insert method inside MasterdetailPage ? Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you inserting a button which when pressed executes `LogoutCommand()`?

Comment: I  tried to inserting command in listview of masterdetailpage, and my list view don't have button that what make its hard

Comment: Can't you insert a button control inside the DataTemplate's `StackLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

You can add a footer to your listview and attach a tap gesture recognizer to it, like this:

```
<ListView.Footer>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#000000" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Padding="20,10,0,10"
                Spacing="20">
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

        <Image Source="YourIcon"
        WidthRequest="60"
        HeightRequest="60"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <Label FontFamily="Panton-LightCaps.otf#Panton-LightCaps" 
        Text="{Binding Title}"
        FontSize="Medium"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        TextColor="White"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ListView.Footer>
```

It should go inside the `ListView` tag.
As you see, it supports Command, so you can use the one you already have.

## Option 2

You can set the TargetType of your sign out item to null and do something like this:

```
private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
    if (item == null)
        return;

    //  Check if sign out was tapped
    if (item.TargetType != null)
    {
        var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
        page.Title = item.Title;

        Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
        IsPresented = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //  Manage your sign out action
        var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Alert!", "Do you really want to exit?", "Yes", "No");
        if (result == true)
        {
            App.AuthenticationClient.UserTokenCache.Clear(Constants.ApplicationID);
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new NewPageLogin());
        }
    }
}
```